# When I convert a data.frame to CSV the datatypes get changed in R

Tags: r, csv, export-to-csv

I want to export a R dataframe to csv. I'm using
1.write.csv or
2.write_csv from readr
to export it to csv. But when I export it, the datatypes gets changed and it gives me wierd results. How can we avoid this issue?

This is the datatypes of the columns in the dataframe

```
> str(Actual_List)
Classes ‘spec_tbl_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    10 obs. of  26 variables:
 $ abc           : chr  "1002018503" "1002018503" "1002018503" "1002018503" ...
 $ xyz           : chr  "11110100" "11110200" "11110300" "11210000" ...
```

This is the datatype of the csv file when I export it to csv and import it later in a different code.

```
 $ abc           : chr  "1002018503" "1002018503" "1002018503" "1002018503" ...
 $ xyz           : num  10000200 10000300 10000400 10000500 10000600 ...
```

This is how I export my csv file,

```
write_csv(data,"./UnitTest/Data/xyz/ExpectedList1.csv")
```

ok to import the csv file I use,

```
dataTb <-read_csv(file="./UnitTest/Data/xyz/ExpectedList1.csv",col_types = cols())
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: csv files don't store information about data types. So what are you referring to?

Comment: To read it back with `read_csv`, use argument `col_types` or with `read.csv`, argument `colClasses`.

Comment: Please provide the command to import the csv file. If `read.csv`, then that function attempts to guess the data types and converts them to the most appropriate type based on the actual data. Read the documentation for more details. But why are you doing this?

Comment: If you want both columns to be parsed as character, then add `col_types="cc")` in the `read_csv` command.